# How to put alert box on controller method in rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alert

I'm developing project on rails 2.3.8 and I need to get alert box on middle of a method in one of my controller. Is it possible to do so on rails ? Please can expert share your idea about this ?

Comment: In the middle of a controller method? Might be worth rethinking this strategy. Usually you want your controller methods to return something... then let something view-related decide how to handle that.

Comment: I just need to check whether my code giving the expected values on different places on my method. That's why I try to get alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), it will allow you to debug your rails process, and you can place breakpoints and then step through your method.

You can resort to the more [manual options of debugging](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html).

Aside from debugging with rubymine, sometimes the fastest way is just writing stuff in the logfile.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to debug you program
 there are many ways to debug

1. Use puts statement in your method puts @user
2. If you are using some IDE then there must be some plugin for it.Ex. for Netbeans there is ruby-debug-ide gem
3. You can use PRY gem to debug your code. I would suggest this one pry